# How to take the pg_dump of a table in csv format while copying it to S3 bucket

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-quicksight

I have a requirement of taking the table backup into S3 in csv format . I already tried taking the `pg_dump` of the tables, but those are in .sql format. Also I tried using gz format, but they all contains the dump of the data. I have tried this command:

```
pg_dump -v -h <hostname>  -d <dbname> -t <tablename> -U <username>| gzip | aws s3 cp - s3://xxx/xxx/tablename.csv.gz
```

Is it possible to get the tables exactly in csv file format so that it could be easy to create QuickSight reports  out of that because we cant use `pg_dump` directly to create the QuickSight reports.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Note: the table size is between 50 to 100 GB

Comment: Is your PostgreSQL database running on Amazon RDS, or EC2 or your own computer?

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein , its running on Amazon RDS

Comment: I would recommend: [Exporting data from an RDS for PostgreSQL DB instance to Amazon S3 - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/postgresql-s3-export.html)

Comment: hi @JohnRotenstein, i tried to do the export and it is working following the steps you mentioned, but while importing i am getting thie error
function aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, aws_commons._s3_uri_1) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Why are you using "import from S3"? I though your goal was to export it to S3. Into what are you importing?

Comment: i am checking for both  the things actually , importing it to postgresql

Comment: I suggest that you either ask a new question, or add appropriate details into this Question (rather than just in a comment).

Comment: Is there any way to export the csv file in gz format ??actually directly uploading it in csv format took more time

Answer (score 1):

You can use `COPY` command to take data dump in `CSV`.

Server Side Export:

```
copy table_name to 'Absolute/path/to/filename.csv' csv header;
```

Client Side Export:

```
\copy table_name to 'Relative/path/to/filename.csv' csv header;
```

Comment: This does not work with Amazon RDS because there is no access to the filesystem.

Comment: Oh, but how are you working with pg_dump utility if you don't have OS access. please confirm if you have psql utility access.

Comment: `psql` and `pg_dump` run externally and connect to the database via an SQL login. They can write to the 'local' filesystem. However, the `COPY` command executes on the server.

Comment: Right , There is a difference between `COPY` and `\COPY`.  `\COPY` writes on client machine. and it can be used via `psql` with -c parameter. hope this helps you.

Comment: Ah, nice! Let's hope that helps them.